# trying to edit tts package in aeneas python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-to-speech, espeak, pyttsx

I started working with aeneas for python, I'm running the code on an ubuntu machine
I wanted to change the default tts -espeak- to  another tts like macos

```
$python -m aeneas.tools.execute_task\
 ara.mp4  ara.xml\ "task_language=ara|os_task_file_format=srt|is_text_type=plain**|tts=macos|tts_path=macos**"     ara.srt
```

but it never works and throws an error at me saying it's not supported, whitle the documentation says that arabic is supported by macos, but i feel that adding the tts namd and path isn't effective at all

```
[ERRO] An unexpected error occurred while executing the task:
[ERRO] Unexpected error while executing task : Language 'ara' is not supported by the selected TTS engine
```

any help changing the used tts

Answer (score 1):

You should use tts as outside of the config_string.
For example:

```
$python -m aeneas.tools.execute_task\
 ara.mp4  ara.xml\
-r="tts=macos" "task_language=ara|os_task_file_format=srt|is_text_type=plain" ara.srt
```